# /questions/id route problem: comments section is not returned when there aren't comments on question

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments

Something is changed on questions route called with `comments= True`:

http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/questions/1940243?body=True&comments=True&pagesize=1&page=1

It does not return the comments section that should be:

```
"comments": []
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Woops, minor regression there.

Should be resolved.